# outside of foreach loop query doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, foreach

Here I'm trying to insert the datas again into database new table (with quantity & customer details). `$grocery_id` and `$grocery_item` values are fetch from database. `$customername`, `$customermobile`, `$groqty` values are user will enter the details in that appropriate textfield.

When I execute this code (`$groceryid`, `$groceryitem`) -> These two column always stored the last row values. Because I've put the query outside of foreach loop. Here is my problem. If I put the query inside the foreach it works fine. But, quantity values doesn't work properly. So, How can I execute the query properly (outside of foreach loop)?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $grocery_id = $rowid;
        $grocery_item = $rowsitem;
        $customername = $_POST['customername'];
        $customermobile = $_POST['customermobile'];
        $groqty = $_POST['groceryquantity'];

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($groqty); $i++)
        {
            $groqtys = $groqty[$i];

            foreach($grocery_id as $key => $index_id )
            {           

            }       

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".customer_order." SET grocery_id = '$index_id' , grocery_item = '$grocery_item[$key]', customername = '$customername', customermobile = '$customermobile', quantity = '$groqtys' ";
            mysql_query($sql,$CN);
            $response = asort_form_ok("Your order successfully submitted. We will deliver you soon.");
        }
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Put both inside the `foreach` loop ? The `$groqtys` and your query.

Comment: What do you expect, when they are outside ?

Comment: @iamsleepy: I've tried. But quantity values stored multiple times???

Comment: You have multiple loops

Comment: @RoyalBg : I want to insert all the values into db table. But, It inserted last row values only ALWAYS

Comment: @Learner if the keys are equal of both arrays, use one loop, and put the `$key` or `$i` whatever you use for key in the loop, for both array keys

Comment: With the present data, there's not enough to determine the number of values in each variable. Does your POST contain multiple values? If so , which and how many? Is the array `$grocery_id` equal to the number of POST values?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : Yes, POST contain multiple values and $grocery_id also equal to the POST values.

Comment: And is the number of `$groqtys` = number of `$grocery_item` ?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : yes all are same

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : I have added a sample screenshot.

Comment: Oh and I forgot, what about `$customername` and `$customermobile`. Is that an array or a single value?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : No, That is a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use one `foreach` loop considering the index values of `$grocery_id` and `$groqty` are the same.

Try:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $grocery_id = $rowid;
    $grocery_item = $rowsitem;

    // sanitizing your values
    $customername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customername']);
    $customermobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customermobile']);
    $groqty = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['groceryquantity']);
    foreach($grocery_id as $key => $index_id)
       {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . customer_order . " SET grocery_id = '$index_id' , grocery_item = '$grocery_item[$key]', customername = '$customername', customermobile = '$customermobile', quantity = '$groqty[$key]' ";
        mysql_query($sql, $CN);
        $response = asort_form_ok("Your order successfully submitted. We will deliver you soon.");
       }

    }

?>
```

**Also note:**

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: but quantity column fields does not store into db? `$groqtys[$key]`?

Comment: I have changed `$groqtys[$key]` into `$groqty[$key]`

Comment: @Learner Ah sorry, didn't notice the difference.

Comment: Its ok. Thanks for spend some time to clear my doubts. I have already use PDO statements. But, my senior says use mysql. So, only i'm using mysql query

Comment: @Learner God forbid if ever your database is hacked, blame it all on your senior then >:D